# Pass referral code on iOS through install

Tags: ios, firebase, facebook-ios-sdk, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to give a link to an user to download my app through the app store (iOS). In this link I want to include an invitation code.

1. How do I create these links?
2. How can I see get the referral code from the link the user clicked on after they install my app?

I read about `Firebase Dynamic Links`. but I quite don't understand how to build the link and with method of Firebase Dynamic Links i will need to use to retrieve the invitation code. Do i will need to handle links received as `Universal Links` (so catch it from `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:`) or handle links received through my app's custom URL scheme (so catch it from `application:openURL:options:`)

I read also about `facebook appLink` but their also i don't know how to do ...

Comment: Any updates on this post owner and  @clayjones94. I'll give huge bounty.